# Invalid encryption key after website published

Tags: asp.net, encryption

So i managed to encrypt my connectionstrings on my localhost, and everything was fine.. it could read without any problems.

Now after i have published my project on my webhote, the story is quite different.

I get following error:

> Key not valid for use in specified state. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8009000B)

Im wondering if i should decrypt it locally and thereafter encrypt it after it has been published to my webhotel? i have seen another thread where people suggest, that a machinekey should be added. but where would i place it, and where would i find it?

the whole stacktrace can be seen [here](http://bkrt.dk/api/Place)

I used the following cmd to encrypt:

```
aspnet_regiis -pef "connectionStrings" "PATH" -prov "DataProtectionConfigurationProvider"
```

Comment: what server do you use ? maybe you try to use some library call for desktop programming only ?

Comment: its just a standard iis server that i have rented

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i figured that the following error is yielded when the machinekey doesnt correspond with the key that has been used to encrypt the string in the first place (my localhost).

Therefore i had to make the following method:

```
    private void ProtectSection(string sectionName, string provider)
{
    Configuration config = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~/");
    ConfigurationSection section = config.GetSection(sectionName);

    if (section != null && !section.SectionInformation.IsProtected)
    {
        section.SectionInformation.ProtectSection(provider);
        config.Save();
    }
}
```

And call it in my global.asax file..

By doing so, i first uploaded my web.config **unprotected** and then asked my web hotel encrypt my connection string when the website was run the first time. Obviously it therefore used it's own machinekey, and nothing therefore conflicted.